# Polychoric matrices out of complex survey data in R

Tags: r, correlation, survey, weighted

I'm using R to analyze data from surveys with complex designs. Therefore, I'm utilizing the `survey` package. Is there a way to obtain polychoric correlation matrices in R while taking into account the complex sample design of my data (i.e., I need to use sampling weights)?

The `svycor()` function from the `jtools` package only allows for obtaining Pearson correlation matrices. And the `weightedCorr()` function from the `wCorr` package only allows for obtaining correlations weighted by a single weight and for pairs of variables (not entire matrices at once).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could estimate the population contingency table with `survey::svytable` and then feed it to `polycor::polychor`.

If you need standard errors, the only way I can think of at the moment is to use replicate weights. That is, use `survey::withReplicates` to repeat the procedure above for each replicate.